# Check last Database backup date in C# - SQL Server 2008

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, smo, database-backups

I have a C# windows Forms application and when the start-up Form loads, i want to check the last time a backup was performed on the database the application connects to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a store procedure that does the work for you. then you can execute it within the form's `OnLoad` event or where ever it fits for your need.

Have a look at the below for getting the T-SQL that does the trick

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1601/script-to-retrieve-sql-server-database-backup-history-and-no-backups/

Answer (score 1):

These are taken from my automation of backups:

First get a list of all databases, including their database GUID:

```sql
select db.name, db.database_id, rec.database_guid
  from sys.databases db
    inner join sys.database_recovery_status rec on db.database_id = rec.database_id
  where db.source_database_id is null and db.name <> 'tempdb'
```

The condition on `source_database_id` excludes snapshots.

Then using the GUID from the above, get the date of the last *full* backup `type='D'` that isn't `COPY_ONLY`:

```
SELECT MAX(backup_finish_date) as backup_finish_date
  from msdb..backupset
  where type='D' and database_guid = @DbGuid and is_copy_only=0
```